# how to grow grass on path for flowing from one point to another?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, animation-nodes, blender-osm, simulation-nodes

https://www.instagram.com/p/CumziCOrnk5/

I wanted to make animation like this but i want to animation grass on curve like this but it should start growing and end after some time like a loop flowing in this infinite direction.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.